# 3D Texture Object

Tags: cuda, textures, 3d-texture

Currently I have a kernel that uses the following texture reference (a 3d texture of type `unsigned char`):

```
texture<unsigned char, 3, cudaReadModeElementType>  volumeTexture;
```

However, I need to be able to exchange the texture's type. I already templated the kernel so it is able to handle different types. But I was unable to exchange the texture's type or the texture itself while maintaining the old state (i.e. being able to handle `unsigned char` and `unsigned short` at the same time).

That's why I thought of using the texture object API. However, this API does not seem to support 3d textures. The available resource types are `Linear`, `Array`, `MipMappedArray` and `Pitch2D`. None of them seem to be designed for 3d textures. Does the texture object API really not support 3d textures at all?

Are there any workarounds? I could use a 2d texture where the slices are just stacked on top of each other. However, the necessary height for a 512³ entries volume (=512*512=262,144) exceeds the maximum texture2d height (65,536 on my device). So I would have to organize the slices both next to each other and on top of each other, which would result in pretty dirty address calculations which I would like to avoid.

Another way would be to copy the kernel code and exchange the texture reference. But that's not a very clean solution. Can the reference itself be templated somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

Create two texture references:

```
texture<unsigned char, 3, cudaReadModeElementType>  volumeTexture_char;
texture<unsigned short, 3, cudaReadModeElementType>  volumeTexture_short;
```

Then, dynamically bind to the one you need in host code:

```
if (...) {
   cudaBindTexture(0, volumeTexture_char, ...);
}
else {
   cudaBindTexture(0, volumeTexture_short, ...);
}
```

Then, pass in a flag on which one to use in the kernel::

```
my_kernel<<...>>(use_short, ...);
```

Comment: Ok, that would be possible. Let's see if there are other options.